# Stop Android GMail from receiving GTalk offline messages notifications?

Tags: gmail, google-talk

I've been trying to find a way to stop getting notifications on my phone when I receive offline messages to my GTalk account. It's highly annoying to be falling asleep and suddenly receive an email notification on my phone and once I open it, it's someone saying good night or some such.

Anyone know of a possible solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you still want them to show up in your inbox, things get complicated.  You would have to create filters to label every kind of message you *do* want notifications for, and then in the Gmail app you would turn off notifications for the inbox, followed by syncing and turning on notifications for the label you just created.

If you don't care if they show in your inbox, do the following from the web GMail:

1. Go to `Mail Settings -> Filters -> Create new filter`
2. Put `youraddress@gmail.com` in the **To** field
3. Put `Chat with` in the **Subject** field
4. Hit **Next**
5. Check `Skip the inbox`
6. Hit **Create Filter**

Alternatively you could turn off the saving of chat history, which disables offline messages, but that has its own downsides.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your suggestion. It's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should set some things on your phone:

1. go to "Settings" page,
2. select "Accounts & Sync"
3. unselect "Background data"

You can't receive any Gmail messages, since you stop connecting with Google server. If you want receive Gmail messages, reselect "Background data".